# Comparing string with an input string :: python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to compare an input string but when ever i enter barack as an input, the compiler directly goes to the else condition ignoring the the if condition and giving me the output "Wrong answer"

```
def main():
    First_name = raw_input(" enter the first name of President Obama   :  ") #input
    if First_name == ['b', 'a', 'r','a', 'c', 'k'] :
            print "Correct answer"
        else :
            print "Wrong answer"


    Exit_key = input('Press any key to end')
```

Comment: Why do you think the input is a list?!

Comment: Python strings are not char arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a reason you are doing it like that? Try:

```
if First_name == "Barack" :
```

Comment: `if First_name.lower() == barack` will be more pythonic

Answer (score 1):

`raw_input` is a string so to do what you want you would have to call list on the string:

```
if list(First_name) == ['b', 'a', 'r','a', 'c', 'k'])
```

It is easier to just do `if First_name ==  "barack"`

```
In [1]: inp = raw_input()
barack

In [2]: list(inp)
Out[2]: ['b', 'a', 'r', 'a', 'c', 'k']

In [3]: inp
Out[3]: 'barack'
```

Answer (score 0):

using `lambda` and `map`. just if you want to learn basic concept

```
if map(lambda x:x,First_name.lower()) == ['b', 'a', 'r','a', 'c', 'k']:
```